# How do I append a string to a Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

The following code:

```
from pathlib import Path
Desktop = Path('Desktop')
SubDeskTop = Desktop + "/subdir"
```

gets the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-eb31bbeb869b> in <module>()
             1 from pathlib import Path
             2 Desktop = Path('Desktop')
       ----> 3 SubDeskTop = Desktop+"/subdir"

     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'PosixPath' and 'str'
```

I'm clearly doing something shady here, but it raises the question:  How do I access a subdirectory of a `Path` object?

Comment: The current answers all understand that the OP really wanted to *join* another path. But what if you *really* wanted to append an arbitrary string (e.g. `.tmp`)?

Comment: How about this? 'Path(str(orig_path)+”.tmp”)'

Comment: `Path(str(orig_path)+".tmp")`

Comment: Rather ugly to have to go via strings to add something like a file extension or just the latter part of a file name. Wish there were something better.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

- The correct [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) to extend a `pathlib` object is `/`

```py
from pathlib import Path

Desktop = Path('Desktop')

# print(Desktop)
WindowsPath('Desktop')

# extend the path to include subdir
SubDeskTop = Desktop / "subdir"

# print(SubDeskTop)
WindowsPath('Desktop/subdir')

# passing an absolute path has different behavior
SubDeskTop = Path('Desktop') / '/subdir'

# print(SubDeskTop)
WindowsPath('/subdir')
```

- When several absolute paths are given, the last is taken as an anchor (mimicking [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)’s behavior):

```py
>>> PurePath('/etc', '/usr', 'lib64')
PurePosixPath('/usr/lib64')

>>> PureWindowsPath('c:/Windows', 'd:bar')
PureWindowsPath('d:bar')
```

- In a Windows path, changing the local root doesn’t discard the previous drive setting:

```py
>>> PureWindowsPath('c:/Windows', '/Program Files')
PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files')
```

- Refer to the documentation for addition details pertaining to giving an absolute path, such as `Path('/subdir')`.

Resources:

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

  - [Basic use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use)
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Comment: These code examples (at least the first) error. One of the issues is `WindowsPath` isn't imported. But after it is, I get this error (py 3.9.10) when I create instances: `File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1084, in __new__\n\traise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"\nNotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system` I'm using cygwin so it might be related.

Answer (score 41):

What you're looking for is:

```
from pathlib import Path
Desktop = Path('Desktop')
SubDeskTop = Path.joinpath(Desktop, "subdir")
```

the `joinpath()` function will append the second parameter to the first and add the '/' for you.

**BEWARE** `SubDeskTop = Path.joinpath(Desktop, "/subdir")` won't work. The slash before subdir ruins it.  (From Patrik in the comments).

Comment: That works, though I learned the '/' operator is overloaded to do the same thing.

Comment: Good point.  I mostly use the `path` module in `os` so the usage is a bit different.  `Path` creates a path object but in `os.path` the returned object is a string so it couldn't call that function on itself.  Good to know, TIL.

Comment: BEWARE: `SubDeskTop = Path.joinpath(Desktop, "/subdir")` won't work. The slash before `subdir` ruins it.

Comment: Your solution is good, But you didn't mention that the Path returns `WindowsPath` object or `LinuxPath` object depends on the OS, So if you're using front/back slash it's a bit crucial, because Linux is front slash, And Windows is back slash.

for example:

`Path.joinpath(Path('/etc/somthing'), 'versions.txt')`

we'll get
`WindowsPath('/etc/somthing/versions.txt')`