# Is there a Pathlib alternate for os.path.join?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I am currently accessing the parent directory of my file using `Pathlib` as follows:

```
Path(__file__).parent
```

When I print it, and this gives me the following output:

```
print('Parent: ', Path(__file__).parent)
#output
/home/user/EC/main-folder
```

The `main-folder` has a `.env` file which I want to access and for that I want to join the parent path with the `.env`. Right now, I did:

```
dotenv_path = os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent, ".env")
```

which works. But I would like to know, if there is a `Pathlib` alternate to `os.path.join()`?
Something like:

```
dotenv_path = pathlib_alternate_for_join(Path(__file__).parent, ".env")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Append a String To A Path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190959/how-do-i-append-a-string-to-a-path-in-python)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators

Comment: Also see this [comparison between os.path and pathlib in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [`pathlib.Path.joinpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath):

```
(Path(__file__).parent).joinpath('.env')
```

Comment: Although I think it is better to spread this out more this is art

Answer (score 128):

Yes there is:

```
env_path = Path(__file__).parent / ".env"
```

`/` is all you need. This will work in different OSs

Comment: Does it support `Path(__file__).parent / "../env"`

Comment: You can always do, Path(__file__).parent.parent / "env"

Comment: Or `Path(__file__).parents[1] / "env"`

Answer (score 11):

Is the following definition of `filepath` closer in spirit to os.path.join?

```
import pathlib
main_dir = 'my_main_dir'
sub_dir = 'sub_dir'
fname = 'filename.tsv'
filepath = pathlib.PurePath(main_dir, sub_dir, fname)
```

Comment: I realize my suggestion may not directly address the context of the original question, but searching for "pathlib os.path.join alternative" returns this page as a top result :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can simply join Path objects and strings:

```py
    import pathlib
    script_parent_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
    my_dir = ".env"
    my_new_path = pathlib.Path(script_parent_path, my_dir)
    print(my_new_path)
```

That's because:

> Pathlib's constructors accept *pathsegments*. Each element of *pathsegments* can be either a string representing a path segment, an object implementing the [os.PathLike](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike) interface which returns a string, or another path object - https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath

Answer (score 5):

Just for anyone wondering how `/` works internally in `pathlib.Path`:

```
    # this is where the magic begins! (overload the '/' operator)
    def __truediv__(self, key): 
        try:
            return self._make_child((key,))
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented


    def _make_child(self, args):
        drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
        drv, root, parts = self._flavour.join_parsed_parts(
            self._drv, self._root, self._parts, drv, root, parts)
        return self._from_parsed_parts(drv, root, parts)


    @classmethod
    def _from_parsed_parts(cls, drv, root, parts):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self._drv = drv
        self._root = root
        self._parts = parts
        return self  # finally return 'self', which is a Path object.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to join paths is to use

```
Path(Path(__file__).parent,".env")
```

See also [definition of `pathlib.Path(*pathsegments)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths).

In the documentation the following statement and example is given for PurePath:

> When several absolute paths are given, the last is taken as an anchor
> (mimicking os.path.join()’s behaviour):
>
> `>>> PurePath('/etc', '/usr', 'lib64')`
>
> `PurePosixPath('/usr/lib64')`
>
> `>>> PureWindowsPath('c:/Windows', 'd:bar')`
>
> `PureWindowsPath('d:bar')`